Do Model.find() on replicate MongoDB
Hi everyone i have a problem and i need to solve for my project of university. One of my teachers said i needed a replicate database but when i make a simple request Model.find() return a error message : Operation `users.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms.
docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.1'
services:

  DB1:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "21017:27017"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USR}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PWD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
    volumes:
      - dbdata6:/data/db

  DB2:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "21018:27018"
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USR}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PWD}
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: test
    volumes:
      - dbdata7:/data/db


code NodeJS:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async function Run() {


    var s = await mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:gizmov-cavdob-nanQo7@127.0.0.1:21017,127.0.0.1:21018/test',

        {
            authSource: "admin",
        }
    ).then(
        () => {
            console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
        },
        err => {
            console.error(err);
        }
    );

    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
}

app.get(`/collectLastId`, async (req, res) => {
    var s = await require('../models/User.model.js').makeModel();

    var data = (await s.find({}));

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.end(s.toString());
});


I would like know how i can use Model.find() with two DB.
Thanks!

The error occurs because you're attempting to connect to a MongoDB replica set, but you haven't configured it as a replica set. MongoDB treats multiple hosts in the connection string as a replica set, requiring the replica set to be properly initialized and configured.

Configure the Replica Set:

Add the replicaSet option in your docker-compose.yml:
command: ["--replSet", "rs0"]


Initialize the replica set after starting the containers:
docker exec -it <DB1_container_name> mongo
rs.initiate({
    _id: "rs0",
    members: [
        { _id: 0, host: "DB1:27017" },
        { _id: 1, host: "DB2:27018" }
    ]
})




Update the Connection String:
Add replicaSet=rs0 to the connection URI:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://root:gizmov-cavdob-nanQo7@127.0.0.1:21017,127.0.0.1:21018/test?replicaSet=rs0', {
    authSource: "admin",
});




I cannot execute the command 1.2 the command return "the input device is not a TTY"

Use the following command to access your MongoDB container:
docker exec -it <DB1_container_name> /bin/bash

I think this should work

Dont work ... when i add the line "command: ..." on docker-compose.yml the container of docker was turning off, every time i tried start the containers.
